# Integrate Composer with existing project autoloader

Tags: php, twig, composer-php

I'm updating a project and I've decided to update my Twig version. I deliberately haven't updated it in the past because of the fact you now need to use Composer, but I've eventually given in to this and decided to install a newer version.

However, it's messing around with my Autoload functions and not loading Twig properly, and I really don't want to have to use it. In a blank file with only the code to autoload Composer it works, so I know my autoloader is clashing. I can see that I'm going to have to use it to some degree, because Twig now requires it. I'm only interested in using it for third-party code, and I don't want to use it for anything else. So what I'm looking for is my own autoloader to try first, and then if I can't load a class by my own means, to try using the Composer autoloader. Third-party code exists in a subdirectory of "Lib". So With Twig, it sits in Lib/vendor/twig/twig/src.

At the moment, I'm checking the first part of the namespace and if it isn't matching my own, I'm trying to load the Composer autoload.php file in Lib/vendor/autoload.php, and then returning back out of my autoload function. But this doesn't seem to be finding the class.

Is what I'm trying to do actually possible? How would I approach something like this?

** Edit - Current Autoloader **

```
public static function autoloader($classname)
{
    /* Separate by namespace */
    $bits = explode('\\', ltrim($classname, '\\'));
    $vendor = array_shift($bits);

    /* If this doesn't belong to us, ignore it */
    if ($vendor !== 'Site')
    {
        // We don't want to interfere here
        if ($vendor == 'Forum')
            return;

        // Try to see if we can autoload with Composer, if not abort
        include_once(SITE_ROOT.'include/Lib/vendor/autoload.php');
print_r(spl_autoload_functions ( ));
        return;
    }

    $class = array_pop($bits);
    $namespace = empty($bits) ? 'Site' : ('Site\\'.implode('\\', $bits));

    $sources_dir = false;
    $path = SITE_ROOT.'include/';
    foreach (array_merge($bits, array($class)) as $i => $bit)
    {
        if ($i === 0 && $bit == 'Lib')
        {
            $bit = mb_strtolower($bit);
            $sources_dir = true;
        }
        else if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]/", $bit)) // Applications only contain lowercase letters
        {
            if ($i === 0)
                $path .= 'apps/';
            else
                $sources_dir = true;
        }
        else if ($i === 1 && ($bit == 'Api' || $bit == 'Cli' || $bit == 'Ajax')) // The API/CLI/AJAX interfaces have slightly different rules ....
        {
            $bit = mb_strtolower($bit);
            $sources_dir = true;
        }
        else if ($sources_dir === false)
        {
            if ($i === 0)
            {
                $path .= 'components/';
            }
            else if ($i === 1 && $bit === 'Application')
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                $path .= 'sources/';
            }

            $sources_dir = true;
        }

        $path .= $bit.'/';
    }

    /* Load it */
    $path = \substr($path, 0, -1).'.php';
    if (!file_exists($path))
    {
        $path = \substr($path, 0, -4).\substr($path, \strrpos($path, '/'));
        if (!file_exists($path))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    require_once($path);

    if (interface_exists("{$namespace}\\{$class}", FALSE))
    {
        return;
    }

    /* Doesn't exist? */
    if (!class_exists("{$namespace}\\{$class}", FALSE))
    {
        trigger_error("Class {$classname} could not be loaded. Ensure it has been properly prefixed and is in the correct namespace.", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your current autoload look like?

Comment: I've updated my question and added the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It might be too late to load Composer's autoload.php within the custom autoload.**

You should not worry too much about performance issues and just load both your custom autoloader and Composer's autoload one after to other. You can optimize a little by prioritizing these autoloaders based on which classes will you load more often (your own or those installed via Composer).

Also, your own/custom autoloader should only care about successful loading and not throw errors if something is not found. Leave that to PHP, this could help with compatibility with other autoloaders.